# XSLT sort specific value

Tags: sharepoint, sorting, xslt

I have XSLT where

```
<xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
<xsl:sort select="@ows_plstx" order="ascending" />
```

I need to output, where first sort value is defined text value @ows_plstx='specific value' and then xslt sort other @ows_plstx values in ascending order.

Example

First defined @ows_plstx specific value

Other @ows_plstx values

...

...

How can I achieved that? Sorry, I am not very familiar with XSLT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the fact that boolean true converts to the number 1 and boolean false converts to the number 0

```
<xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
  <xsl:sort select="number(@ows_plstx = 'specific value')"
            order="descending" data-type="number" />
  <xsl:sort select="@ows_plstx" order="ascending" />
```

`number(@ows_plstx = 'specific value')` is 1 for the "specific value" and 0 for all other values, so sorting in descending order by those numeric values should put the "specific value" first.  Technically the `number()` call in that select isn't necessary but I think it makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: @Ketlin glad it worked, and welcome to Stack Overflow. For future reference when you get an answer that solves your problem you should consider _accepting_ it by clicking the tick mark to the left.